# Skyfield versus PyEphem

Tags: python, astronomy

Can some one tell what the real difference is between Skyfield and PyEphem?

They are more or less on the same website:

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/
http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/

It seems to me that development is going on with Skyfield because the most recent entry on the website is from 2017 March 15.

This is a little bit confusing so some clarification from an authoritative source would be very helpful.

Kind regards

Klaus

Comment: This comment should summon @brandon-rhodes to this place.

Answer (score 0):

Skyfield is PyEphem but rewritten from scratch. Skyfield is pure python, pyephem is a wrapper around a C library.

Here’s a YouTube Video from the author. https://youtu.be/FVEEndIwOSA